# Replace a xml tag or change the value of a xml tag in java

Tags: java

Iam new to java . Iam having my xml content as below

```
<Configuration>   
    <A>OFF</A>   
    <B>OFF</B>   
    <C>OFF</C>   
    <D>OFF</D>  
    <E></E>   
    <F>200</F>   
    <AB>
         <G>10001</G>
         <H>10002</H>
         <I>10003</I>
         <J>10004</J>    
    </AB>    .............    ......
```

I want to change the value of `<B>` tag to `ON` . How can i achieve this? I am using the below code

```
String config2=config;
if(config2.contains("<B>OFF</B>"))
{
    config2=config2.replace("<B>OFF</B>","<B>ON</B>");
    return config2;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The quick and dirty way: string replacement. The clean way: parsing the xml with a parser, modify the dom, save it as xml.

Comment: Please provide the java code where you are parsing the xml

Comment: String config2=config;
if(config2.contains("<B>OFF</B>"))
{
config2=config2.replace("<B>OFF</B>","<B>ON</B>");
return config2;
}
else
{
return true;
}

Comment: Edit your question and past your code.

Comment: You can do it without `if-else` statement and return the new string just in a single line `config.replace("<B>OFF</B>", "<B>ON</B>")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method can not return two different types at same time.

return `config2` in `else` part too if the return type of your method is `String`.

`else
{
return config2;
}`

If the string contains the chars then edit the `config2` and return it else return same `String` without editing